# Launching ASP.NET Core 1 app from console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, dnx

While dotnet cli is not yet ready to work with Visual Studio and dnu/dnx gives me huge amount of extra unneeded libraries I want to do the following.

I want to launch ASP.NET Core 1 project either using command line or console app using traditional .csproj approach.
I created a ASP.NET 4 project, included all dependencies and was able to compile it.

1st Attempt.
At first I tried to compile it into console app and launch through standard entry point:

```
    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
    }
```

It says: "No service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.IApplicationEnvironment' has been registered."

Which means that dnx.exe creates additional dependency injection rules probably through PlatformServices.Create. 
Does somebody know how to do it properly?

2nd Attempt
I compiled it into dll and tried to launch it through dnx.exe which gave me the error "Error: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting'. Available commands: web.".

Here's my project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://*:5004"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {}
  },
  "entryPoint": "ManagementConsoleWeb",
  "loadable": false
}
```

So what's the proper way? Is is possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

Here're some thoughts.

1. ASP.NET Core 1 requires DNX bootstrap to work. Yes, it works under .NET 4.5.2 but DNX is a must. So basically it's strange you can reference ASP.NET Core 1 libraries in .csproj net451.
2. DNX bootstrap libraries are not available under Nuget for net451 moniker. So you can't reference them from .csproj

That means you can't DEBUG ASP.NET Core 1 using traditional .csproj class library or executable approach. Of course you can always connect to a running app but that's not convenient.

So our team now is working with DNX bootstrap for NET CORE 1 but we deliver outputs from .csproj build until RC2 release.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core 1.0 uses `IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment` instead of  `IApplicationEnvironment applicationEnvironment`. 
Go through [the ASP.NET Core Migration document](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/migration/rc1-to-rtm.html) for full detail.